# PHP - UK Postcode only return sector

Tags: php, postal-code

I'm trying to write a regex function that will return the sector of a postcode.

The user could type the following postcodes:

1. WA14 5
2. WA12 5GJ

I need the regex just to return the sector of the postcode.

I've tried the following but it doesn't work:

`^[a-zA-Z]+\d\d?[a-zA-Z]?\s*\d+`

`^(((([A-Z][A-Z]{0,1})[0-9][A-Z0-9]{0,1}) {0,}[0-9]))$`

Thanks

Comment: Assume many of us are not familiar with UK postal codes. That said, what is the output you are trying to get, i.e., what identifies the sector?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a PHP expert by any means (okay, I don't know anything about it). But this regex will return the value you want in the first capture group.

`^[A-Za-z]{1,2}[\d]{1,2}\s(\d).*$`

From a (brief) reading of the PHP docs, this should return the value you are looking for.

`preg_match('/^[A-Za-z]{1,2}[\d]{1,2}\s(\d).*$/', 'WA12 5GJ', $match); // $match[1] is '5'`

Answer (score 0):

I deal with this in some detail in my [Programmers guide to UK postcodes](https://www.getthedata.com/postcode).

Firstly, the **postcode sector** in WebDevB's example is:

```
WA14 5
```

This graphic shows the format of a UK postcode:

[image: Format of a UK postcode]

The regular expression to match the sector is:

`^[A-Z][A-Z]{0,1}[0-9][A-Z0-9]{0,1} [0-9]`

You would use this in PHP like this:

```
$postcode = 'WA12 5BB';

preg_match('/^[A-Z][A-Z]{0,1}[0-9][A-Z0-9]{0,1} [0-9]/', $postcode, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

This would output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => WA12 5
)
```

The output would be the same whether `$postcode` was `WA12 5BB` or `WA12 5`.